# LOGONSERVER environment variable value in MAC OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, shell, terminal

On windows I can get the `LOGONSERVER`environment variable name by this command.

```
sudo %LOGONSERVER%
```

I need to find the exact thing on MAC OS X. Any help???

Comment: Have you tried `echo` instead of `sudo` & `$LOGONSERVER` instead of `%LOGONSERVER%`?

Comment: it returned empty response. Actually I'm not sure if i will have the same environment variable on MAC as I have on windows.

Comment: ^^ Yes, that was another question. So better google for LOGONSERVER equivalent in OSX

Answer (score -2):

OK. thanks to anisshsane, I found the answer. In Unix/OSX the alternative is `HOSTNAME`. So

```
echo $HOSTNAME
```

did the trick for me.

Comment: These are not the same variable. The LOGONSERVER variable is the active directory *server* that was used to log onto the domain, on mac os, HOSTNAME is the name of the machine you're currently on.